# Trying to create messenger application python

Tags: python, sockets, messenger

Trying to Create Messenger Application within python (cross internet). So far I have successfully been able to send a message to the receiver end and then ping the message back to the user that sent it. However, it does not send the message to all connected users. I think this is because if python is listening for user input the socket cannot receive any data (I might be wrong...).

Below is the client side code:

```
import socket
host = '**.***.***.***' # Public Ip Hidden
port = 5005                   # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
b = input("Please enter your message.")
b = b.encode('utf-8')
s.sendall(b)
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print('Message Received:', repr(data))
```

Now below is the server side code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os
import thread
import threading
from thread import *
from threading import Thread

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 5005 # Arbitrary non-privileged port
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client = ''
clients = set()
clients_lock = threading.Lock()
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    with clients_lock:
        clients.add(client)
    while True:
        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        else:
            print repr(data)
            with clients_lock:
                for c in clients:
                    for d in data:
                        conn.sendall(data)
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))
    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

Any Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use threads in your client code too. Also, it's generally preferable to use `threading.Thread` rather than the low-level `thread` module.

Comment: could oyu give an example of using threading within the client?